# Java checar, mostrar os valores registrados no banco de dados MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, query, select

Preciso de ajuda estou fazendo um jogo em java e preciso de todos os registros e arquivos e etc dos player na minha tabela porem não consigo conectar com o banco de dados e muito menos verificar e exibir os valores

Ps: o tutorial do sun.java de DriverConnector não me ajudou voçês poderiam?
PSS: (executar queryes e checar as integers)

Comment: Acho que podias adicionar mais informação a tua pergunta, estás a falar num jogo desktop certo? (pois nao vais poder responder devido a reputação penso eu)

Comment: Sim Porem é completamente em java 2D mais eu só preciso criar ...                                                            int teste1 =  SELECT * player_data where uuid='japkdawdfa-dawdadd' Algo desse tipo dai em uso um void pra isso colocando entre parateses o uuid dele ou sei lá mais é daquilo que estou travado

Comment: Eu estava a preparar uma resposta mas ja que podes responder, respondo por aqui. **Usas o netbeans?** se sim já pensaste na possibilidade de usar o **Hibernate** é extremamente simples fazer a comunicação como essas query's simples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neste site tem tudo o que você vai precisar para trabalhar com JDBC

[Caelum - Bancos de dados e JDBC](http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/bancos-de-dados-e-jdbc/#2-12-fazendo-pesquisas-no-banco-de-dados)

**Exemplo:**

```java
// pega a conexão e o Statement
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/seubanco", "user", "password");
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from contatos");

// executa um select
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

// itera no ResultSet
while (rs.next()) {
  String nome = rs.getString("nome");
  String email = rs.getString("email")

  System.out.println(nome + " :: " + email);
}

stmt.close();
con.close();
```

Comment: vlw, só o primeiro que eu cliquei parece perfeito, mto obrigado..

Comment: Legal. Não esqueça de marcar a resposta como "correta".

Comment: @NilsonUehara recomendo adicionar o pedaço do código descrito no seu link aqui na resposta, porque se por algum motivo o link não estiver mais disponível a sua resposta continuará útil para todos =)

Comment: @iTSangar bem lembrado. Trecho de código adicionado.

Comment: Mais como eu crio uma connection com minha database?

Comment: @Lucas Pelo jeito você não leu o artigo desde o início, pois lá ele ensina passo-a-passo como fazer isso... de qualquer forma eu alterei o meu exemplo... veja lá.